# how adjust the length of the navigation bar to the size of the phone

Tags: html, css

I have a website coded in html and css which works very well except that the navigation bar does not adapt to the width of small phones! it always overflows regardless of my effort!

here is the code of my navigation bar

that is my html code:

```
<div class="nav-h">
<input type="checkbox" id="nav-check">
<div class="nav-header">
<div class="nav-title"><img src="images/ca.svg"><span><a class="c" 
<a href="#">CAMER</a><a class="s" href="#">-AUTOPRIX</a></span> 
</div>
</div>  
<div class="nav-btn">
<label for="nav-check">
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
</label>
</div>

<div class="nav-links">
<ul>
<li><a  class="feat" href="index.php" target="_self">ACCEUIL</a></li>
<li><a class="feat" href="../html/apropos.php" target="_self">A PROPOS</a></li>
<li><a class="feat" href="../html/contact.php" target="_self">CONTACT</a></li>
<li> <input class="s-search" type="text" name="search0" placeholder="Recherche"><button type="submit" class="searchButton"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button></li>
</ul> 

<div class="containers">
<input type="text" placeholder="Recherche...">
<div class="search"></div>
</div>

</div>
</div>
```

that is my css code:

```
.nav-h {
position: fixed;
top: 0;
left: 0;
width: 100%;
padding: 0;
z-index: 10000;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
-moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
box-shadow: 0 1px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
height: auto;
background-color:transparent;   
padding: 20px 30px;
-webkit-transition: all ease-out .5s;
-moz-transition: all ease-out .5s;
-o-transition: all ease-out .5s;
transition: all ease-out .5s;
background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}

.nav-h > .nav-header {
display: inline;
}

.nav-h > .nav-header > .nav-title {
display: inline-block;
font-size: 22px;
color: #fff;
font-family: 'Black Han Sans';
font-weight: bolder;
padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
}

.nav-h > .nav-btn {
display: none;
}
.nav-h ul li {
display: inline-block;
}
.nav-h ul li a    {
color: #FFF;
text-decoration: none;
display: block;
padding: 10px;
font-family: 'Basic';
transition: 0.3s;
font-family: 'Basic';
font-weight: bolder;
transition: 0.3s;
}
.nav-h > .nav-links {
display: inline;
float: right;
margin-right:310px;
}
.nav-h img{
width: 50px;
margin-left: -10px;
margin-right: 10px;
margin-top: -10px;
}
.nav-h > .nav-links > a {
display: inline-block;
padding: 13px 10px 13px 10px;
text-decoration: none;
color: #FFF;
float: right;
}
```

how to modify my code to adapt my navigation bar to small screens? I remember that apart from my navigation bar all the rest of the code works very well on small screens!

here is my css code for phone screens:

```
@media (max-width:700px) {

.nav-h > .nav-btn {
display: inline-block;
position: absolute;
right: 0px;
top: 0px;
}
.nav-h > .nav-btn > label {
display: inline-block;
width: 50px;
height: 50px;
padding: 13px;
}
 .nav-h > .nav-btn > label:hover,.nav-h  #nav-check:checked ~ .nav-btn > label {
background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
.nav-h > .nav-btn > label > span {
display: block;
width: 25px;
height: 10px;
border-top: 2px solid #eee;
}
.nav-links ul li{
display: block;
font-size: 15px;
padding: 0, 20px;
}
.nav-h >.nav-links{
 position: absolute;
 display: inline;
 width: 100%;
 background-color: #333;
 height: 0px;
 transition: all 0.3s ease-in;
 overflow-y: hidden;
 top: 50px;

 }
 .nav-h > .nav-links > a {
 display: block;
 width: 100%;
 }
.nav-h > #nav-check:not(:checked) ~ .nav-links {
 height: 0px;
 overflow-y: hidden;
 overflow: hidden;
 overflow-x: hidden;
 }
.nav-h > #nav-check:checked ~ .nav-links {
height:200px;
overflow-y: hidden;
overflow: hidden;
overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

Comment: try to use media queries @media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .nav-h{
    width: value;
  }
}

Comment: I did it. I did it  @media only screen and (max-width = 700) {width: 100%;}

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using size unit **vw**?
[Introduction into Viewport unit](https://css-tricks.com/fun-viewport-units/)

Or maybe you forgot to add the viewport **meta tag**?
[Viewport meta tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag)

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Comment: @Anubis do you really mean to insert `<a class="c"` accordingly or it is just a typo?

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the `margin-right` for your `nav-links` class for mobile `(@media)`. The code look like incomplete. If you need any further assistance drop your comment below.

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    position: relative;
}

.nav-h {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    z-index: 10000;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
    box-shadow: 0 1px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
    height: auto;
    background-color: transparent;
    padding: 20px 30px;
    -webkit-transition: all ease-out .5s;
    -moz-transition: all ease-out .5s;
    -o-transition: all ease-out .5s;
    transition: all ease-out .5s;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}

.nav-h > .nav-header {
    display: inline;
}

.nav-h > .nav-header > .nav-title {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 22px;
    color: #fff;
    font-family: 'Black Han Sans';
    font-weight: bolder;
    padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
}

.nav-h > .nav-btn {
    display: none;
}

.nav-h ul li {
    display: inline-block;
}

.nav-h ul li a {
    color: #FFF;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    padding: 10px;
    font-family: 'Basic';
    transition: 0.3s;
    font-family: 'Basic';
    font-weight: bolder;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

.nav-h > .nav-links {
    display: inline;
    float: right;
    margin-right: 310px;
}

.nav-h img {
    width: 50px;
    margin-left: -10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-top: -10px;
}

.nav-h > .nav-links > a {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 13px 10px 13px 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #FFF;
    float: right;
}

ul,
li {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

@media (max-width:767px) {
    .nav-h > .nav-links {
        margin-right: 0;
    }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.2/css/all.css">
<div class="nav-h">
    <input type="checkbox" id="nav-check">
    <div class="nav-header">
        <div class="nav-title"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x150"><span>
          <a class="c" href="#">CAMER</a><a class="s" href="#">-AUTOPRIX</a></span>
        </div>
    </div>
  
    <div class="nav-btn">
        <label for="nav-check">
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
        </label>
    </div>

    <div class="nav-links">
        <ul>
            <li><a class="feat" href="index.php" target="_self">ACCEUIL</a></li>
            <li><a class="feat" href="../html/apropos.php" target="_self">A PROPOS</a></li>
            <li><a class="feat" href="../html/contact.php" target="_self">CONTACT</a></li>
            <li>
                <input class="s-search" type="text" name="search0" placeholder="Recherche">
                <button type="submit" class="searchButton"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
            </li>
        </ul>

        <div class="containers">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Recherche...">
            <div class="search"></div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I already did it. I will add in my question my code for @media